# Hyper Ledger Fabric Pluggable Consensus

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, consensus, pluggable

I would like to work on integrating new consensus algorithms to Hyper Ledger Fabric. Could you please let me know the good starting point for the same. I found this link [https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-spec/#3.4-Pluggable-Consensus-Framework][1] but looking for a tutorial kind of material which describes implementation details with examples.

Answer (score 1):

That page is for Fabric 0.6, it's prehistoric.

The official Fabric documentation is in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/.

In my team we implemented a Byzantine Fault Tolerant consensus for Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 that can be found [here](https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go/).

You can read the paper [here](https://smartbft-go.github.io/paper.pdf).

Comment: Thanks alot for sharing the details. I will go through the links.

Comment: Getting below error while executing make dist-clean all                                              
# out of sync, but ignored, due to noverify in Gopkg.toml:
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware: hash of vendored tree not equal to digest in Gopkg.lock
Makefile:211: recipe for target 'check-deps' failed
make: *** [check-deps] Error 1                 Could you pl tell me what is going wrong here.

Comment: the dependencies are all outdated and out of sync, just ignore it.